# Proof that $A_4$ is the unique group of order $12$ with no subgroup of order six

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is there a simple proof that $A_4$ is the only group of order $12$ containing a subgroup of order six? (i.e. if $G$ is a group of order $12$ not having a subgroup of order six, then $G \cong A_4$?)

Comment: A group of order $4$ has $1$ or $4$ Sylow $3$-subgroups. In the first case, there is a subgroup of order $6$. In the second case, the conjugation action on the Sylow subgroups must be $A_4$, so the group is isomorphic to $A_4$.

Comment: @Derek Holt: Why the conjugation action must be $A_4$ and not $S_4$? And why does the conjugation action on subgroups imply the group is isomorphic to $A_4$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I do not wanted to look up in tables, but looked for a proof not using tables.

Comment: @Stefan: $A_4$ is the only subgroup of order $12$ in $S_4$.

Comment: One Sylow subgroup cannot normalize another, so the conjugation action of an element of order $3$ on the $4$ Sylow $3$-subgroups must be to fix one and act as $3$-cycle on the others. So the group contains $4$ $3$-cycles and has order $12$, so it is clearly $A_4$.

Comment: @Derek Holt: Two questions, 1) why if we have just one Sylow $3$-subgroup we have a subgroup of order $6$, by an element counting argument we do not need to have an element of order $6$?, 2) that an element of order $3$ must fix one is clear (cause it belongs to one of the Sylow $3$-Subgroups), but why it moves every other, and not for example just moves one or two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Claim 1:** $A_4$ has no subgroup of order $6$.

Assume $H$ be a subgroup of order $6$ then $H$ is normal in $A_4$. Let $K$ be subgroup of $H$ eith order $3$ then $K$ must be uniqe subgroup of $H$ with order $3$ so $K$ is normal in $A_4$ contradiction.

**Claim 2:** $A_4$ is only subgroup of $S_4$ with order $12$.

Assume $H$ be another subgroup of order $12$ then we must have $HA_4=S_4$ which means that 
$$\dfrac{|H||A_4|}{|H\cap A_4|}=24 \implies |H \cap A_4|=6$$

which is impossible by claim $1$.

**Claim 3:** Let $H$ be any subgroup of $12$ with has no subgroup of $6$. By calim $1$, we know that it can not have normal subgroup $K$ of order $3$. Let $H$ act on left coset of $K$ by left multiplication then $ker=core(K)=e$ so we have injection from $H$ to $S_4$. By claim $2$ we are done.

Comment: why does the fact that $A_4$ is the only subgroup of $S_4$ with order $12$ imply that $A_4$ is the only subgroup of order $12$ with no subgroup of order $6$?

Comment: it is time for me to sleep :) ,I missunderstoond the question. I will edit my question.

Comment: @Stefan: now it is ok. :)

Comment: "by claim 1, we know that it can not have normal subgroup $K$ [...] Let $H$ act on left coset of $K$ [...]" you let act $H$ on a subgroup that does not exists, sry I do not understand...

Comment: @Stefan: A subgroup $K$ of order $3$ certanly exist, but we said that $K$  can not be normal. When $H$ act on left cosets of $K$, there is a homomorphism from $H$ to $S_4$ as it has $4$ cosets and kernel of this homomorphism is larget normal group contained in $K$, which is denoted as $core(K)$ but since $K$ is nonnormal $core(K)=e$ which means that $H$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$.

Comment: ok, thanks. and in your first comment why must $K$ as a subgroup of order $3$ be the unique subgroup of $H$ of order $3$?

Comment: well, if you have two group in $H$, let say $R,K$ then $RK$ has $9$ element which is impossible thus any group of order $6$ has uniqe (so normal) subgroup of order $3$.

Comment: ok. Now I know why a subgroup of a group of order $6$ could just have a unique order $3$ group, but why follows from this that an order $12$ group could not have a unique (i.e. normal) subgroup of order $3$?

Comment: @Stefan:Notice that if the group have normal subgroup of order $3$ then it must have a subgroup of order $6$.